# Sorting inside ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

How can i sort the output of my ng-options alphabetical?

```
ng-options="obj.name for obj in objList track by obj.key"
```

I thought this would be the solution:

```
ng-options="obj.name for obj in objList track by obj.key | orderBy: 'name'"
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: And your data/output is ?

Comment: We can't help unless you give us your input..

Comment: input : an object containting objects, with a name .. and a key.

Comment: @OmriAharon, actually, the structure of `obj` was well-implied from the question

Comment: @NewDev And `objList` might have not been well formatted.

Comment: @OmriAharon, The OP said that "nothing changed", meaning that `ng-options` worked without sorting, so malformed `objList` hypothesis is not applicable. So, seems like a minor point... but between too-little and too-much info that questions have here on SO, this one stroke the right balance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter should come before the `track by` expression:

```
ng-options="obj.name for obj in objList | orderBy: 'name' track by obj.key">
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ng-options="obj.name for obj in objList | orderBy: 'name'"
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfv42/)